# How to send file upload multipart form in restassured

Tags: api, rest-assured, automation-testing

I want to send below as a **Multipart Form** in API Body for a POST request:

Upload passing two attributes (KEY) with (VALUE)
Send arquivo (KEY) with (file)
How to do this using REST-Assured

multipart print https://ibb.co/0QQCkQv

attempts:

````
Response response = (Response)
given()
.relaxedHTTPSValidation()
.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
.formParam("tipo", "capital_relatorio_faturamento")
.multiPart("arquivo", file, "image/jpg")
enter code here
------------------------------
.formParam("arquivo", "image/jpg")
.multiPart("tipo", "capital_balanco_patrimonial")
.multiPart("arquivo",file)
-------------------------------
.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
.multiPart("tipo", "capital_comprovante_endereco")
.multiPart("arquivo",file)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.multiPart("tipo", "capital_balanco_patrimonial")
.multiPart("arquivo", file, "image/jpg")
```

Rest-assured will automatically add content-type for these.